# User Exit CONFPP05 (T-code co11n) Exception condition "DUPREC" raised

Tags: hook, abap, exit, sap-erp

I'm currently working on the user exit CONFPP05 (T-code co11n)

and I'm facing a problem, when i give error message with type E.

When the program execute that error, the program succesfully run the error message, but after that, when I press ENTER or SAVE button, it gives me a runtime error

here I catch some error

> Exception condition "DUPREC" raised.

Error analysis
A RAISE statement in the program "SAPLCORB" raised the exception
condition "DUPREC".
Since the exception was not intercepted by a superior
program, processing was terminated.

```
Short description of exception condition:


For detailed documentation of the exception condition, use
Transaction SE37 (Function Library). You can take the called
function module from the display of active calls.
-


Trigger Location of Runtime Error
 Program                                 SAPLCORB
 Include                                 LCORBU08
 Row                                     100
 Module type                             (FUNCTION)
 Module Name                             CO_RU_DI_AFRU_INSERT
```

Comment: Can you provide us the code of your user exit ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to confirm if we had access to your code.

However, the export parameters for the user exit are CAUVD_TAB (table of orders) and AFRUD_TAB (table of confirmations). I think that when you are showing your error message, you are not exiting the function properly and are still appending either or both of these tables.  This means that when the database tries to update, it ends up with a duplicate key which results in the runtime error.